# thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)` left: `22`, right: `4`' when installing Rust for WSL

Tags: rust, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I go to the website and see a script to download the Rust installer:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

I changed some things in the `Customize Installation` option and proceed with the installation then get the following error:

```
info: profile set to 'complete'
info: setting default host triple to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2020-05-04, rust version 1.45.0-nightly (65b448273 2020-05-03)
warning: Force-skipping unavailable component 'lldb-preview-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
warning: Force-skipping unavailable component 'rls-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: downloading component 'cargo'
  5.0 MiB /   5.0 MiB (100 %)   3.2 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'llvm-tools-preview'
info: downloading component 'miri'
  1.7 MiB /   1.7 MiB (100 %) 672.4 KiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rust-analysis'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
 12.2 MiB /  12.2 MiB (100 %)   3.2 MiB/s in  4s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rust-src'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 15.8 MiB /  15.8 MiB (100 %)   3.9 MiB/s in  4s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 60.5 MiB /  60.5 MiB (100 %)   3.0 MiB/s in 17s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustc-dev'
 63.4 MiB /  63.4 MiB (100 %)   3.7 MiB/s in 19s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
  3.4 MiB /   3.4 MiB (100 %)   3.0 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'cargo'
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `22`,
 right: `4`', src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:166:21
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `22`,
 right: `4`', src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:166:21
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7fb935adbc9c - backtrace::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h65597d255cb1398b
                               at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.40/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:88
   1:     0x7fb935adbc9c - backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::hd4f479d7150ec4a0
                               at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.40/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66
   2:     0x7fb935adbc9c - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h015072984a2b172c
                               at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:77
   3:     0x7fb935adbc9c - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h6df05d3335f32194
                               at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:61
   4:     0x7fb9357ba81c - core::fmt::write::h1f444f4312eb6c27
                               at src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:1028
   5:     0x7fb935adb526 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h8d147888220078ef
                               at src/libstd/io/mod.rs:1412
   6:     0x7fb935adb19e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h8a6df0fa81d6af62
                               at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:65
   7:     0x7fb935adb19e - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h6f05b4733407e509
                               at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:50
   8:     0x7fb935adb19e - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h0d0a23bd02315dd8
                               at src/libstd/panicking.rs:188
   9:     0x7fb935ada943 - std::panicking::default_hook::h8d15a9aecb4efac6
                               at src/libstd/panicking.rs:205
  10:     0x7fb935ada943 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hbe174577402a475d
                               at src/libstd/panicking.rs:464
  11:     0x7fb935ada4be - std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt::h4d855dad868accf3
                               at src/libstd/panicking.rs:373
  12:     0x7fb935ada450 - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt::ha0f013e3301a9528
                               at src/libstd/panicking.rs:328
  13:     0x7fb935aaae86 - <rustup::diskio::threaded::Threaded as rustup::diskio::Executor>::join::hf33124263a81d2a4
  14:     0x7fb935aaa636 - core::ptr::real_drop_in_place::haa8255139d9471a2
  15:     0x7fb9357d5190 - core::ptr::real_drop_in_place::h04c627b98e68397b
  16:     0x7fb935a9e777 - rustup::dist::component::package::unpack_without_first_dir::h352b57d236248e9a
  17:     0x7fb935a762f6 - rustup::dist::manifestation::Manifestation::update::h8c800deec8167b5b
  18:     0x7fb935a64b8a - rustup::dist::dist::try_update_from_dist_::h113375517e7a85ca
  19:     0x7fb935a4964c - rustup::toolchain::Toolchain::install::h048b51ffab245b48
  20:     0x7fb935a46c8c - rustup::toolchain::Toolchain::install_from_dist::h00b9aafeb93470e5
  21:     0x7fb9357143ee - rustup_init::self_update::install::h4cee0e396cee456b
  22:     0x7fb935725ca2 - rustup_init::run_rustup_inner::ha545371fd2dc19a6
  23:     0x7fb935722d64 - rustup_init::main::hba9a23e308c96901
  24:     0x7fb9356b7a03 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h1778d9ce6385bef5
  25:     0x7fb93572c458 - main
  26:     0x7fb9352070b3 - __libc_start_main
  27:     0x7fb9356b4029 - <unknown>
thread panicked while panicking. aborting.
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I also tried installing with stable as default and the same thing happened where it panics on the assertion `(left == right)`. What might have caused this?

Comment: What WSL distribution are you using? What package manager are you using?

Comment: @tgiachetti Ubuntu, apt

Answer (score 4):

This issue is here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2245

The problem:

> microsoft/WSL#4898 seems to be the underlying cause; glibc has now implemented nanosleep in terms of clock_nanosleep, which depends on an unsupported WSLv1 codepath https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2019-11/msg00155.html

Solution is to downgrade glibc.

> This affects Arch Linux installation on WSL. The solution is to downgrade glibc:
>
> `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/glibc-2.30-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

The above command is specific to downgrading glibc for Arch WSL. I would try the similar command for your given WSL distribution package manager.

It looks like [STEEL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317804/942317) has given the way of doing this for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 Version 1909 Build 18363.959 using Ubuntu and WSL1. Was able to solve it using the workaround that I found here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2245#issuecomment-656918060

Simply execute the following commands:

```
export RUSTUP_IO_THREADS=1
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Thanks to Marcus Cobden for this solution (see GitHub link)

Comment: This would result in the following error:
rustup: Unable to run interactively. Run with -y to accept defaults, --help for additional options

To solve:
https://github.com/kata-containers/tests/issues/2187#issuecomment-567192642

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y`

Answer (score 0):

```
pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/g/glibc/glibc-2.30-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

this is for arch wsl installation
using this to rollback glibc if you recently installed wsl
and this is just adding to the answer given by @tgiachetti

Comment: if pacman doesn't work answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232422/880052) was help

Answer (score 0):

Since I had existing Ubuntu installed with WSL 1. And after updating WSL 1 to WSL2 I had to do below fix. And it works now `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --list --verbose
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
```

This advised fix mentioned at Rust github -> https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2245

Comment: Unfortunately, WSL2 does not support IPv6, so switching to WSL2 is not the solution.

Comment: it is as mentioned on git issue. And it worked for me :)

Comment: It does not answer the question.